# Airflow: How to pass prev_execution_date- 2 hour

Tags: airflow

I am using below airflow variables in my sql query & want to pass ***prev_execution_date- 2 hours*** in query. Is there any direct way of doing same in airflow

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM {mysql_table_name} WHERE {incremental_column} >= " \
                "  '{{{{ prev_execution_date.to_datetime_string() }}}}' " \
                " AND {incremental_column} < " \
                "  '{{{{ execution_date.to_datetime_string() }}}}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Airflow uses the Pendulum library for datetime and `prev_execution_date` is a Pendulum object (docs: https://pendulum.eustace.io). This supports various methods such as [`subtract`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#addition-and-subtraction):

```py
prev_execution_date.subtract(hours=2)
```